# c# Moving label from right to left

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code in C# Windows forms. This code makes the label text moves from right to left. But when the text disapears, it doesn't come again from right to left.. 
Anyone please help

```
label21.Location = new Point(label21.Location.X - 15, label21.Location.Y);

if (label21.Location.X > this.Width)
{
     label21.Location = new Point(0 - label21.Width, label21.Location.Y);  
}
```

Comment: `label1.Width` is used instead of `label21.Width`

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre is right you are resetting your label's position by using the width of another label. Using `- label21.Width` would be enough though.

Comment: What text was displayed initially before disapearing?

Comment: I just typed wrong here.. I have the right label21 in my original code. Still same problem 

My labeltext is "Something is here......"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this:

```
label21.Location.X - 15
```

you move your label to the left.

But `X > this.Width` checks if `X` is more than right side (it is not possible when moving left).

Your check should be:

```
if (label21.Location.X + label21.Width < 0)
{
     label21.Location = new Point(this.Width, label21.Location.Y);  
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. the label text moves but doesn't disappear. Just when it hits the left side, it starts again from right.

Comment: @SinanLaBlaugranaHendi, do you want label to disappear in the left side and then appear in right side?

Comment: Yesss please :)

Comment: @SinanLaBlaugranaHendi see edited answer: `if (label21.Location.X + label21.Width < 0) `

Comment: That works fine - but a little issue. When the text starts again from right, it doesn't starts from zero. the text appears from the right, but not from the start point. If you understand what I mean :)

Comment: @SinanLaBlaugranaHendi, see edited: `label21.Location = new Point(this.Width, label21.Location.Y);`

Comment: You are a Hero - Thanks so much ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the code, `label1` should be `label21`.

Correct it as follows:

```
label21.Location = new Point(label21.Location.X - 15, label21.Location.Y);

if (label21.Location.X > this.Width)
{
     label21.Location = new Point(0 - label21.Width, label21.Location.Y);  
}
```

Comment: I just typed wrong here.. I have the right label21 in my original code. Still same problem

Answer (score 1):

`this.Width` is the "rightmost point" of the containing control.
Since you are moving left you label's location X is going towards 0 and not towards this.Width.

Comment: Can you please explain more - can I do something about it?

Answer (score 0):

This could do the work
If label goes completely into left, then it disappears and comes from right from the beginning.

```
        Point a = new Point(this.Width, label4.Location.Y);
        Point b = new Point(label4.Location.X-10, label4.Location.Y);
        if (label4.Location.X < 0-label4.Width+1)
        {
            label4.Location = a;
        }
        else
        {
            label4.Location = b;
        }
```